# Torrent scrap via PHP

Tags: php

Estou fazendo scrap de torrente, e o script funciona no localhost, com o xampp server, e no servidor o hostgator ele não funciona, alguém sabe porque ?

scrap.php

```
<?php
include "httptscraper.php";

try{
            $timeout = 2;

            $scraper = new udptscraper($timeout);
            $ret = $scraper->scrape('udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80',array('7C90CFEE93DE8C4FA04526DAA5CE530ADFB8DF6E'));

            print_r($ret);
        }catch(ScraperException $e){

            echo('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n");
            echo('Connection error: ' . ($e->isConnectionError() ? 'yes' : 'no') . "<br />\n");
        }
?>
```

httptscraper.php

```
<?php
    /*  Torrent UDP Scraper
        v1.2

        2010 by Johannes Zinnau
        johannes@johnimedia.de

        Licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
        http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

        It would be very nice if you send me your changes on this class, so that i can include them if they are improve it.
        Thanks!

        Usage:
        try{
            $timeout = 2;

            $scraper = new udptscraper($timeout);
            $ret = $scraper->scrape('udp://tracker.tld:port',array('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'));

            print_r($ret);
        }catch(ScraperException $e){
            echo('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n");
            echo('Connection error: ' . ($e->isConnectionError() ? 'yes' : 'no') . "<br />\n");
        }
    */

include "tscraper.php";

    class udptscraper extends tscraper{


        /*  $url: Tracker url like: udp://tracker.tld:port or udp://tracker.tld:port/announce
            $infohash: Infohash string or array (max 74 items). 40 char long infohash. 
            */
        public function scrape($url,$infohash){
            if(!is_array($infohash)){ $infohash = array($infohash); }
            foreach($infohash as $hash){
                if(!preg_match('#^[a-f0-9]{40}$#i',$hash)){ throw new ScraperException('Invalid infohash: ' . $hash . '.'); }
            }
            if(count($infohash) > 74){ throw new ScraperException('Too many infohashes provided.'); }
            if(!preg_match('%udp://([^:/]*)(?::([0-9]*))?(?:/)?%si', $url, $m)){ throw new ScraperException('Invalid tracker url.'); }
            $tracker = 'udp://' . $m[1];
            $port = isset($m[2]) ? $m[2] : 80;


            $transaction_id = mt_rand(0,65535);
            $fp = fsockopen($tracker, $port, $errno, $errstr);
            if(!$fp){ throw new ScraperException('Could not open UDP connection: ' . $errno . ' - ' . $errstr,0,true); }
            stream_set_timeout($fp, $this->timeout);


            $current_connid = "\x00\x00\x04\x17\x27\x10\x19\x80";


            //Connection request
            $packet = $current_connid . pack("N", 0) . pack("N", $transaction_id);
            fwrite($fp,$packet);


            //Connection response
            $ret = fread($fp, 16);
            if(strlen($ret) < 1){ throw new ScraperException('No connection response.',0,true); }
            if(strlen($ret) < 16){ throw new ScraperException('Too short connection response.'); }
            $retd = unpack("Naction/Ntransid",$ret);
            if($retd['action'] != 0 || $retd['transid'] != $transaction_id){
                throw new ScraperException('Invalid connection response.');
            }
            $current_connid = substr($ret,8,8);


            //Scrape request
            $hashes = '';
            foreach($infohash as $hash){ $hashes .= pack('H*', $hash); }
            $packet = $current_connid . pack("N", 2) . pack("N", $transaction_id) . $hashes;
            fwrite($fp,$packet);


            //Scrape response
            $readlength = 8 + (12 * count($infohash));
            $ret = fread($fp, $readlength);
            if(strlen($ret) < 1){ throw new ScraperException('No scrape response.',0,true); }
            if(strlen($ret) < 8){ throw new ScraperException('Too short scrape response.'); }
            $retd = unpack("Naction/Ntransid",$ret);
            // Todo check for error string if response = 3
            if($retd['action'] != 2 || $retd['transid'] != $transaction_id){
                throw new ScraperException('Invalid scrape response.');
            }
            if(strlen($ret) < $readlength){ throw new ScraperException('Too short scrape response.'); }
            $torrents = array();
            $index = 8;
            foreach($infohash as $hash){
                $retd = unpack("Nseeders/Ncompleted/Nleechers",substr($ret,$index,12));
                $retd['infohash'] = $hash;
                $torrents[$hash] = $retd;
                $index = $index + 12;
            }


            return($torrents);
        }
    }
?>
```

tscraper.php

```
<?php
    /*  Torrent Scraper Base Class
        v1.0

        2010 by Johannes Zinnau
        johannes@johnimedia.de

        Licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
        http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

        It would be very nice if you send me your changes on this class, so that i can include them if they are improve it.
        Thanks!

        Usage:
        See udptscraper.php or httptscraper.php
    */


    class ScraperException extends Exception {
        private $connectionerror;


        public function __construct($message,$code=0,$connectionerror=false){
            $this->connectionerror = $connectionerror;
            parent::__construct($message, $code);
        }


        public function isConnectionError(){
            return($this->connectionerror);
        }
    }


    abstract class tscraper {
        protected $timeout;


        public function __construct($timeout=2){
            $this->timeout = $timeout;
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: o sistema gera alguma mensagem de erro? aparece alguma coisa nos logs da tua aplicação?

Comment: não aparece nada nos logs, o script gera uma mensagem que é Error: Could not open HTTP connection.
 Connection error: yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infelizmente, parece que sua aplicação viola os termos de uso do Hostgator

"User may not: Run any bit torrent application, tracker, or client."

Fonte: http://forums.hostgator.com/torrent-tracker-t38637.html

Parece que você terá que mudar de servidor ou negociar isso com a Hostgator.